# html5 canvas for multiple image uploads not uploading all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I'm trying to resize multiple images through html5 filereader api on client side . It works fine for a single image but for multiple images , it usually uploads only one image and leave the rest and i cannot get what is the problem . Here is my code

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {


        var filesToUpload =  evt.target.files;

         for (var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++) {



            var img = new Image();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            reader.onload = function(e) {img.src = e.target.result; 
            };


            img.onload = function (){    // also tried reader.onloaded here

            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);



            var MAX_WIDTH = 300;    // 2048
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 150;   // 1600
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;



            if (width > height) {
              if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
              }
            } else {
              if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
              }
            }


            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);


            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");



            var newImgs = new Image();
            newImgs.src = dataurl;

            document.body.appendChild(newImgs);


        }    

    }
```

Comment: Where is the part of your code that does the upload?

Comment: You seem to be having some serious scoping issues in your for loop. You realize all iterations of a for loop run in the same scope, right?

Comment: filesToUpload is the input file multiple type . so when it changes , it triggers the function handleFileSelect

Comment: i am aware of the problem but i need to know a solution

Comment: ... fix it? code with the fact that they're all in the same scope in mind? if you know that you have a problem with scoping, what have you done to try to solve it?

Comment: i meant i tried with different variable names in each loop by use arrays but that didn't work either

Comment: All code after the reader.onload needs to be INSIDE the reader.onload callback. You need to create a private scope for each iteration of the loop. You need to bind to the image.onload before setting the src.